# Анимация popup, пример

Tags: jquery, анимация, popup

Очень понравилась анимация на сайте http://wezom.com.ua/contacts. Это когда нажимаешь на телефон, и выскакивает popup окно. Гуглю уже целый день. Может кто сталкивался?

Answer (score 2):

Нашел все таки в гугле. Этот эффект реализуется с помощью css, а именно 'transform':'perspective(600px) rotateX(20deg)'